# Check if column name from one dataframe matches with index value of another dataframe and populate value into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df_rates and df_profit as shown below. df_rates has a time-date value its column name with values as certain rates and the index values denotes the minutes before the time-date value of the column. (i.e. row 1 denotes 0 mins before 2012-03-31 23:45:00, row 2 denotes 5 mins before  2012-03-31 23:45:00 and so on).  Whereas df_profit has timestamps as its index and there is a  Profit column.

I want to add the Profit column from df_profit as a new column to df_rates under the following condition:

1.       If the timestamp (2012-03-31 23:45:00) at index of df_profit matches with the column name of df_rates (2012-03-31 23:45:00), then populate the new column with the corresponding profit value (354.664).

2.       The next value (125.76) in line from Profit column of df_profit, where the timestamp is ‘2012-03-31 23:30:00’ should be populated in the new column against row where ‘Mins before time’ is 15 and so on. (Since the difference in time between 2012-03-31 23:45:00 and 2012-03-31 23:30:00 is 15 mins)

I have been trying a lot on how to do it but I am at a loss. Could someone please help or guide with this?

```
df_rates
Mins before time     2012-03-31 23:45:00
0                        113.1
5                        112.1
10                       113.1
15                       113.17
20                       103.17
25                       133.17
30                       101.39


df_profit
                         Profit
2012-04-01 00:30:00      251.71
2012-04-01 00:15:00      652.782
2012-04-01 00:00:00      458.099
2012-03-31 23:45:00      3504.664
2012-03-31 23:30:00      1215.76
2012-03-31 23:15:00     -21.48
2012-03-31 23:00:00     -8.538
    

Expected dataframe:
Mins before time    2022-01-31 23:45:00+01:00   New_column
0                      113.1                     3504.664
5                      112.1    
10                     113.1    
15                     113.17                    1215.76
20                     103.17   
25                     133.17   
30                     101.39                    -21.48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the original answer (see below), here is a very straightforward way to do what OP asks:

```py
df_rates['Profit'] = df_profit.Profit.reindex(df_rates.columns[-1] - pd.to_timedelta(df_rates['Mins before time'], unit='min')).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
   Mins before time  2012-03-31 23:45:00    Profit
0                 0               113.10  3504.664
1                 5               112.10       NaN
2                10               113.10       NaN
3                15               113.17  1215.760
4                20               103.17       NaN
5                25               133.17       NaN
6                30               101.39   -21.480
```

Explanation:

- create a Series of Timestamps by subtracting from the Timestamp label of the final column in df_rates (assumed to be of Timestamp type, otherwise wrap it in `pd.to_datetime()`) a Series of timedelta values created using the `Mins before time` column with units of minutes
- use `reindex` on df_profit to create a Series of profit figures that parallels the columns of df_rates and contains the `Profit` values from df_profit where the Timestamp labels in the df_profit index exactly match those in the Series of Timestamps created in the previous step, and NaN elsewhere
- convert that Series of profit figures (possibly including NaNs) to a numpy array with `to_numpy` and use it to initialize a new column labeled `Profit` (or whatever other label is desired) in df_rates.

---

**Original answer:**

Here's a way to do it:

```py
df_rates = ( df_rates
    .set_index(df_rates.columns[-1] + pd.to_timedelta(-df_rates['Mins before time'], unit='min'))
    .join(df_profit).reset_index(drop=True) )
print(df_rates)
```

Output:

```
   Mins before time  2012-03-31 23:45:00    Profit
0                 0               113.10  3504.664
1                 5               112.10       NaN
2                10               113.10       NaN
3                15               113.17  1215.760
4                20               103.17       NaN
5                25               133.17       NaN
6                30               101.39   -21.480
```

Explanation

- set the index of df_rates to be the label of its final column (assumed to be of Timestamp type, otherwise wrap it in `pd.to_datetime()`) plus a Series of timedelta values equal to the `Mins before time` column with units of minutes
- use `join` with df_profit to add a `Profit` column with non-null values in rows with matching index values, and reset the index.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise answer and explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to loop through the code if I have multiple columns in df_rates with column name of various timestamps. And have the corresponding new column created after every column?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible. You may want to post that as a new question.

Comment: Sure, thank you.  Could you kindly check a similar question I have posted on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814522/compare-a-timestamp-with-another-between-2-dataframes-and-populate-values-into-a?noredirect=1#comment132035000_74814522) but with slightly different answer expected?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to get the profits at corresponding tiemstamps:

```py
# import dateutil.parser
# from datetime import timedelta

def getProfit_atDelay(delayMins, startTime, profitDF):
    try: 
        startTime = dateutil.parser.parse(str(startTime))
        dTime = startTime - timedelta(minutes=int(str(delayMins)))
        return profitDF['Profit'].loc[dTime]
    except: return None
```

(I'm assuming that `df_profit` index contains datetime datatype; otherwise, edit code to convert `dTime` to the matching datatype.)

---

And to get all the values for the new column:

```py
def profits_for_rates(ratesDF, profitDF):
    rStart, rMins = ratesDF.columns[1], ratesDF['Mins before time']
    return [getProfit_atDelay(t, rStart, profitDF) for t in rMins]
```

---

If you use it like

```py
df_rates['New_column'] = profits_for_rates(df_rates, df_profit)
```

then `df_rates` will look like

```py
   Mins before time  2012-03-31 23:45:00  New_column
0                 0               113.10    3504.664
1                 5               112.10         NaN
2                10               113.10         NaN
3                15               113.17    1215.760
4                20               103.17         NaN
5                25               133.17         NaN
6                30               101.39     -21.480
```