# Compare a timestamp with another between 2 dataframes and populate values into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df_rates and df_profit as shown below. df_rates has a time-date value its column name with values as certain rates and the index values denotes the minutes before the time-date value of the column. (i.e. row 1 denotes 0 mins before 2012-03-31 23:45:00, row 2 denotes 5 mins before  2012-03-31 23:45:00 and so on).  Whereas df_profit has timestamps as its index and there is a  Profit column.

I want to add the Profit column from df_profit as a new column to df_rates under the following condition:

1. If the column name of df_rates is '2012-03-31 23:45:00', then find the timestamp that is 30 mins before it i.e. '2012-03-31 23:15:00' in the index of df_profit, then populate the new column with the corresponding profit value (-21.48) at row where 'Mins before time' is 0.
2. The next value (-8.538) in line from Profit column of df_profit, where the timestamp is ‘2012-03-31 23:00:00’ should be populated in the new column against row where ‘Mins before time’ is 15 and so on.

With some help I implemented the below code but that grabs and populates the value from the matching timestamp on df_profit index. I am unsure on how to grab value from the df_profit index that is 30 mins before the column name of df_rates. Could someone kindly help?

```
df_rates
Mins before time     2012-03-31 23:45:00
0                        113.1
5                        112.1
10                       113.1
15                       113.17
20                       103.17
25                       133.17
30                       101.39

df_profit
                         Profit
2012-04-01 00:30:00      251.71
2012-04-01 00:15:00      652.782
2012-04-01 00:00:00      458.099
2012-03-31 23:45:00      3504.664
2012-03-31 23:30:00      1215.76
2012-03-31 23:15:00     -21.48
2012-03-31 23:00:00     -8.538
2012-03-31 22:40:00     -5.11

Expected dataframe:
Mins before time    2022-01-31 23:45:00+01:00   New_column
0                      113.1                     -21.48
5                      112.1    
10                     113.1    
15                     113.17                    -8.538
20                     103.17   
25                     133.17   
30                     101.39                    -5.11
```

Implemented code :

```
df_rates['New column'] = df_profit.Profit.reindex(pd.to_datetime(df_rates.columns[-1]) - pd.to_timedelta(df_rates['Mins before time'], unit='min')).to_numpy()
```

Comment: In this case I think numpy select will be quite helpfull with your map

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```py
anchor_time = df_rates.columns[-1]
lookback_minutes = 30
df_rates = ( df_rates
    .set_index(anchor_time - pd.to_timedelta(df_rates['Mins before time'] + lookback_minutes, unit='min'))
    .join(df_profit).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'Profit':'New_column'}) )
```

Output:

```
   Mins before time  2012-03-31 23:45:00  New_column
0                 0               113.10     -21.480
1                 5               112.10         NaN
2                10               113.10         NaN
3                15               113.17      -8.538
4                20               103.17         NaN
5                25               133.17         NaN
6                30               101.39      -5.110
```